# Call a method on close of msg box - extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a custom message box; below is the code for it.

```
var myMasks = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp('salesFrm').el, {useMsg: false});
myMasks.show();
var msg = Ext.Msg.show( {                   
    msg:'<br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'+'Enter Valid Quantity',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
    modal: false,
    closable: true,
    draggable: true,
    animEl: 'mb7',
    y:10,
    cls: 'msgbox',
    fn: function(btn){
        if(btn == 'ok'){            
        myMasks.hide();
    } 
}
});
```

On click of the 'OK' button, the mask on the underlying panel is hidden.
The same **doesn't** happen on click of the 'close' button at the right corner.
I tried searching for writing any handler method for the same but couldn't do so successfully.

Can anyone help me out on how to hide the mask on the underlying panel on click of the 'close' button?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback runs any time the message box closes. As it reads...

```
fn: function(btn) {
    if (btn == 'ok') {            
        myMasks.hide();
    } 
}
```

...it will only close the mask when the OK button is clicked. If you always want it to close just running...

```
fn: function(btn) {          
    myMasks.hide();
}
```

... instead does the trick. (tested locally in ExtJS 5)

Comment: On removing the if condition, the mask didn't hide. Instead of removing the `if` condition, is there any similar condition like `if(btn=='close')`?